# Convert an int pointer to a char pointer when the int values are guaranteed to be less than 256 in C

Tags: c, string, pointers

I have an `int*`:

```
int arr[4];
int *x = arr;
x[0] = 65;
x[1] = 66;
x[2] = 67;
x[3] = 0; // terminating null
```

Then I want to print these values as characters:

```
char *y = magical_function(x);
printf(y);
```

The output should be `ABC`. How do I get or define this magical function?

Note: If I happened to have this: `x[2] = 1000;`, then I honestly don't care what the answer does. It may ignore the higher bits, error, whatever, it's UB in this case.

This doesn't work:

```
char *y = (char*) x;
```

...since the output is just `A`, probably since the `char*` interprets the int as 4 chars and the 2nd of those chars is a null byte, which ends the string:

```
int arr[4];
int *x = arr;
// x points to the following memory:

 x->01000000 (x[0])
    00000000
    00000000
    00000000 (65)
    -------- (x[1])
    01000001
    00000000
    00000000
    00000000 (66)
// if casted to a char*:

y->01000000 "A"
   00000000 "\0"
   00000000 "\0"
   00000000 "\0" etc.
```

Comment: @EugeneSh. It's just an array actually. `int arr[]; int *x = arr;`

Comment: Since there is no magic, you will have to perform the conversion element-wise.

Comment: to have a char pointing to the byte with the value < 0x100 you need to take into consideration the endianess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`int` and `char` probably have different sizes, so you can't just cast the pointers, as they would be read/written incorrectly. If you have an array of integers and you need an array of some other type, be that `char`, `float`, or just a differently sized integer, you need to make a new array and convert each item.

```
/*magical_function*/
/*Assuming arr is "null terminated". Don't forget to call free().*/
char *int_to_char_array(int *arr)
{
    size_t len = 0;
    int *p = arr;
    do {
        ++len;
    }  while (*p++);
    char *out = malloc(len); // Allocate space needed for same number of chars
    for (size_t i = 0; i < len; ++i)
        out[i] = (char)arr[i]; // convert each element
    return out;
}
int main() {
    // As in OP
    int arr[4];
    int *x = arr;
    x[0] = 65;
    x[1] = 66;
    x[2] = 67;
    x[3] = 0; // terminating null

    char *str = int_to_char_array(arr);
    printf("%s\n", str); // or any normal string function
    printf("length %i\n", strlen(str));
    free(str);
}
```

Runnable demo: http://tpcg.io/fPETPE

Comment: http://tpcg.io/fPETPE if the OP has an array as specified, will create a null terminated string from it.

Comment: @P__J__ Well, its impossible to just cast a 4 element int pointer into a 4 element char pointer and get the same numbers. If he want's literally the same pointer, then maybe can do it in-place.

Answer (score 1):

In that case I would just change the format specifier to %c

e.g.:

```
int a = 65;
printf("%c\n", a);
```

Comment: The cast you proposed makes the conversion: char * y = (char *) x. The problem is at your printf. If the format specifier is for integers it will cast y to an integer. That's why it prints the ASCII value of y.

Comment: Just printf("%c\n", x[0]) and see what happens.

Comment: I want to print the entire string, not just a character. What if I want `y[1]`? It would give me part of the `x[0]` **integer**, since an integer is 4 bytes wide.

Comment: Ok, now I see what you mean. You can't make that kind of cast since the memory allocated to the int array will use 4 bytes. It can't know that you want only the first byte of each position. The y array would have to point to segmented blocks of memory. The only way I know you could do that is with a loop iterating the int array and printing each element as a char.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to print these values as characters...The output should be ABC. How do I get or define this magical function?

It's called `printf` and it's definition located in `stdio.h`. See more here: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/printf/

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int arr[4] = {65, 66, 67, 0};

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) printf("%c", arr[i]);

    return 0;

}
```

Tested code here: http://tpcg.io/AFwhXt

Comment: Suggest `i < 4` --> `arr[i] != 0`

Comment: But I don't want to print the chars. I want to put them in a char array/pointer.

Answer (score 1):

The following code is based on the basis of being `0` of the last element in the input.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char *
magical_function (int const *x) {
    size_t numOfElements = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    for (i = 0; x[i] != 0 ; ++i, ++numOfElements) ;
    char *p = malloc(numOfElements + 1);
    if (!p) {
        perror("malloc error");
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < numOfElements; ++i) {
        p[i] = (char)x[i];
    }
    p[i] = 0;
    return p;
}

int
main (void) {
    int arr[4];
    int * const x = arr;

    x[0] = 65;
    x[1] = 66;
    x[2] = 67;
    x[3] = 0;

    char *y = magical_function(x);
    puts(y);
    free(y);

    return 0;
}
```